# Import csv file (a line of string)

Tags: python, csv

Here my csv file content:

```
'GK', 'M', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'M'
```

I try to import the csv file to python program as a list of string as:

```
['GK', 'M', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'M']
```

However through `csv.reader` it returns a list of list and contains only **one** string as:

```
["'GK', 'M', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'M'"]
```

I tried to figure out the solution, but it took too many steps as follows:

```
import csv
filepath = 'positions copy.csv'
file = open(filepath)
data = file.read().splitlines()
print(data)
data_2 = ''.join(data)
print(data_2)
data_3 = data_2.replace("'", "").replace(" ","")
print(data_3)
positions = data_3.split(',')
print(data_4)
```

Any shorter solution?

Comment: You can simply split the original 1 string via `data[0].split(', ')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an answer using csv-reader, it is done using some of the various optional parameters for csv-reader, you can see all of them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params).  Note that `delimeter` defaults to ',' so you don't strictly need it in your example:

```
import csv

with open("positions copy.csv",'rt') as f:
    print(next(csv.reader(f,delimiter = ',', quotechar = "'", skipinitialspace = True)))
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Maybe you could add that `delimiter=","` is the default value, and maybe a link to the documentation of the options of [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params).

Comment: @nqtuan87 Then you should accept the answer as the best one.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
with open('file1.txt',encoding='utf-8') as data:
    print(data.read().strip().strip('"'))
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'pandas' module.

```
import pandas as pd
file=pd.read_csv('Your File')
```

now the file is pandas DataFrame but if you want numpy ndarray add this:

```
file=file.values
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a file in the current directory (`data.csv`) with the following contents:

`'GK', 'M', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'M'`

The following code will:

1. Read the contents from the file to the `data` variable
2. Split the `data` string into a list of strings, delimited by the character sequence `,`
3. Remove any instances of the character `'` from each list item
4. Strip any leading/trailing white-space from each list item

```py
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
     data = f.read()

data = [ s.replace('\'', '').strip() for s in data.split(', ') ]
```

The result is a list of strings (`data`) that looks like this when `print(data)` is called:

```py
['GK', 'M', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'M']
```